# Display back button of action bar is not going back in Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am developing an Android app. I am using ActionBar with AppCompactActivity. In my app, I add back button to action bar. But when I click on it, it is not going back to the previous activity. For example, I start activity 2 from activity 1. Activity 2 contains action bar with back button. But when I click on action bar back button of activity 2, it is not going back to activity 1.

This is how I set action bar for activity 2:

```
public class EditProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.edit_profile);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.profile_action_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        setTitle("Edit Profile");
        ActionBar actionBar= getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

This is how I started activity 2 from activity 1:

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
```

It is not going back when I click this button

[image]

Why it is not going back?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Add the following to your activity.You have to handle the click event of the back button.

```
@Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
      switch (item.getItemId()){
         case android.R.id.home:
              onBackPressed();
              return true;
       }
   return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I am gonna green up the answer soon. But I already upvoted.

Comment: A real hero here :)

Answer (score 11):

Here you have 2 options:

a) provide a `parentActivityName` to your `SecondActivity` tag in AndroidManifest.xml like this:

```
 <activity
    ...
    android:name=".SecondActivity"
    android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
```

b) override `onOptionsItemSelected` in `SecondActivity` like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
    case android.R.id.home:
        onBackPressed();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

I would suggest reading [this guide](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html) for more information.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest not to handle "android.R.id.home" in onOptionsItemSelected as it is brittle. Rather you should override `onSupportNavigateUp` method.

```
@Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
      switch (item.getItemId()){
         case android.R.id.home:
              onBackPressed();
              return true;
       }
   return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
 }
```

Note:  If you are using `onOptionsItemSelected` , then you should return false as default otherwise `onSupportNavigateUp` method is not called.

Comment: Your note helped. I always used _onSupportNavigateUp _ and never override both onOptionsItemSelected and onSupportNavigateUp together before. returning false in onOptionsItemSelected works

Answer (score 1):

Here is your code

```
 public class EditProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.edit_profile);
            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.profile_action_toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            setTitle("Edit Profile");
            ActionBar actionBar= getSupportActionBar();
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
                   finish();
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Add this to your Activity, in `onCreate()`**

```
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(v -> {
        //What to do when back is clicked
        finish();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, always see Android Guidelines http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/design/patterns/navigation.html to prevent Google blocks Android apps.

Try to add this code in your Activity

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
            break;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to override onOptionsItemSelected and check the item's id, if it is equals with home button's id, just call onBackPressed method.

```
@Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
                onBackPressed();
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define what should happen when you click on that button, this can be done in your second activity's [onOptionsItemSelected](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onOptionsItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem)) method. Notice the `android.R.id.home` constant which refers to the activity's back button that you want to use.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

    case android.R.id.home:

        finish(); //close the activty
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

enable actionbar backbutton in onCreate()

```
 if (getSupportActionBar() != null){
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Streaks");
        }
```

override backbuttonPressed method

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

override method

```
 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        onBackPressed();
        return true;
    }
```