# Why doesn't the toolbar back button work?

Tags: android

I added a `Toolbar` to my `Activity` with back arrow like this:

```
Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);        
setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
//add back arrow - but it doesn't go back, nothing happens when I click it
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

But when I click the back arrow, it doesn't go back to previous page

Comment: I think this link can help you [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36457564/display-back-button-of-action-bar-is-not-going-back-in-android/36457747)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add this lines:

```
@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    onBackPressed();
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    finish(); // or your code
}
```

Comment: why not just `finish()` in `onSupportNavigateUp()`?

Comment: Very good question. This is because the nav button will do what the back button is supposed to do - So if you perform operations on the back button, you will not have to perform them again (code duplication prevention)

Answer (score 1):

You need to override `onCreateOptionsMenu()` and `onOptionsItemSelected()` just like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.your_id, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Don't forget to replace R.menu.your_id with your id as name suggest.

Answer (score 0):

With suggested answers you might want to add `parentActivity` in your Android manifest.xml

```
<application ... >
...
<!-- The main/home activity (it has no parent activity) -->
<activity
    android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" ...>
    ...
</activity>
<!-- A child of the main activity -->
<activity
    android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
    android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" >
    <!-- The meta-data element is needed for versions lower than 4.1 -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" />
</activity>
```

Docs: [Android developers](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal#SpecifyParent)